# onMouseMove get mouse position

Tags: javascript, position, mouse, dom-events, onmousemove

In Javascript, within the Javascript event handler for onMouseMove how do I get the mouse position in x, y coordinates relative to the top of the page?

Answer (score 29):

if you can use jQuery, then [this](http://api.jquery.com/mousemove/) will help:

```
<div id="divA" style="width:100px;height:100px;clear:both;"></div>
<span></span><span></span>
<script>
    $("#divA").mousemove(function(e){
      var pageCoords = "( " + e.pageX + ", " + e.pageY + " )";
      var clientCoords = "( " + e.clientX + ", " + e.clientY + " )";
      $("span:first").text("( e.pageX, e.pageY ) - " + pageCoords);
      $("span:last").text("( e.clientX, e.clientY ) - " + clientCoords);
    });

</script>
```

here is pure javascript only example:

```
var tempX = 0;
  var tempY = 0;

  function getMouseXY(e) {
    if (IE) { // grab the x-y pos.s if browser is IE
      tempX = event.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft;
      tempY = event.clientY + document.body.scrollTop;
    }
    else {  // grab the x-y pos.s if browser is NS
      tempX = e.pageX;
      tempY = e.pageY;
    }  

    if (tempX < 0){tempX = 0;}
    if (tempY < 0){tempY = 0;}  

    document.Show.MouseX.value = tempX;//MouseX is textbox
    document.Show.MouseY.value = tempY;//MouseY is textbox

    return true;
  }
```

Comment: hmm, js example seems very similar to http://www.codelifter.com/main/javascript/capturemouseposition1.html except without the handy comments

Comment: `id="#divA"` and `$("divA")` -- someone was asleep when writing this

Comment: @RozzA thanks for paying attention.

Comment: voted your answer up coz i ended up using part of it anyway :)

Comment: What is the argument to getMouseXY(e) ?

Answer (score 10):

This is tried and works in all browsers:

```
function getMousePos(e) {
    return {x:e.clientX,y:e.clientY};
}
```

Now you can use it in an event like this:

```
document.onmousemove=function(e) {
    var mousecoords = getMousePos(e);
    alert(mousecoords.x);alert(mousecoords.y);
};
```

**NOTE:** The above function will return the mouse co-ordinates relative to the viewport, which is not affected by scroll. If you want to get co-ordinates including scroll, then use the below function.

```
function getMousePos(e) {
    return {
        x: e.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft,
        y: e.clientY + document.body.scrollTop
    };
}
```

Answer (score 6):

It might be a bit overkill to use [d3.js](http://d3js.org/) just for finding mouse coordinates, but they have a very useful function called `d3.mouse(*container*)`.  Below is an example of doing what you want to do:

```
var coordinates = [0,0];
d3.select('html') // Selects the 'html' element
  .on('mousemove', function()
    {
      coordinates = d3.mouse(this); // Gets the mouse coordinates with respect to
                                    // the top of the page (because I selected
                                    // 'html')
    });
```

In the above case, the x-coordinate would be `coordinates[0]`, and the y-coordinate would be `coordinates[1]`.  This is extremely handy, because you can get the mouse coordinates with respect to any container you want to by exchanging `'html'` with the tag (e.g. `'body'`), class name (e.g. `'.class_name'`), or id (e.g. `'#element_id'`).

Comment: +1, but **Fair Warning**: This approach is a little too sluggish for use against `onmousemove`. I already had d3.js in my project so I tried it, but it's just not spry enough for my use case.

Answer (score 4):

Especially with mousemove events, that fire fast and furious, its good to pare down the handlers before you use them-

```
var whereAt= (function(){
    if(window.pageXOffset!= undefined){
        return function(ev){
            return [ev.clientX+window.pageXOffset,
            ev.clientY+window.pageYOffset];
        }
    }
    else return function(){
        var ev= window.event,
        d= document.documentElement, b= document.body;
        return [ev.clientX+d.scrollLeft+ b.scrollLeft,
        ev.clientY+d.scrollTop+ b.scrollTop];
    }
})()
```

**document.ondblclick=function(e){alert(whereAt(e))};**