# onmousemove event

Tags: javascript, events, onmousemove

I want to change the left and top style element with javascript on an onmousemove event, but it does not work.

My code for the onmousemove event:

```
function mymove(e)
{
var event=new MouseEvent(e);
    x = 20;
    y = 10;     

    document.getElementById('mye').style.left = event.pageX + x+'px' ;
    document.getElementById('mye').style.top = event.pageY - y+'px';


    }
```

Comment: Don't do the `var event=new MouseEvent(e);` statement. The function argument already is the correct event object. Just use it.

Answer (score 3):

Guessing on the markup and CSS. Also, I think the `e` properties might change per browser. This works in Firefox (9).

**CSS**

```
#mye {
    height: 25px;
    width: 250px;
    position: absolute;
    background: #ddd;
}
```

**Markup**

```
<div id="mye">Content</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
var mymove = function (e) {
    var x = 20,
        y = 10,
        mye = document.getElementById('mye');

    mye.style.left = (parseInt(e.clientX) + x) + 'px';
    mye.style.top = (parseInt(e.clientY) - y) + 'px';
};

// Don't forget to add this in an onload or ondomready.
document.getElementById('mye').onmousemove = mymove;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3YdEa/6/

And note, as Jeffrey Sweeney mentions, attaching to the `window.onmousemove` is probably more common:

```
window.onmousemove = mymove;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3YdEa/7/

Here is [Quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_properties.html#position) on the mouse event position property situation. This is a few years old, however.

Here's another [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3011418/onmousemove-get-mouse-position), and of course [jQuery's `$.mousemove()`](http://api.jquery.com/mousemove/), which will eliminate the differences between browsers.

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to apply the event to the window?

Comment: Possibly. Just depends on what they're trying to do. [Demo of `window.onmousemove`](http://jsfiddle.net/3YdEa/4/).