# How to open PopUp right beside the event Button - how to get Mouse Cursor Position onclick?

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, mouse, coordinates

if i do have a call on an imagebutton like this:

onclick="window.open('link','width=615,resizable,scrollbars').focus(); return false;

how i can open this just right besides the action Button?
or how how to get Mouse Cursor Position onclick?

events are not working here
onclick="window.open('link','width=615,resizable,scrollbars,**left=e.pageX**').focus();

also not working here
onclick="window.open('link','width=615,resizable,scrollbars').moveTo(e.pageX,0);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the elements:

event.pageX and event.pageY to get the coordinate relative to the document

you can see more details here:
[mozilla.org - pageX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/event.pageX)

obs: the "e" on your code stands for "event", try to change it to event
and if your trying to insert the left/top value by css you need to add a +'px' to concatenate, because event.page returns only the number.

Answer (score 0):

How about looking [here](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials%3aMouse_Position) for mouse position

Answer (score 0):

Check this link to get mouse position
[onMouseMove get mouse position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3011418/onmousemove-get-mouse-position)

You can attach a function to the onclick event, and in the function you can call window.moveTo(x, y) to move the window to the position you need

```
 function openWindow() {
    var win = window.open(...);
    win.moveTo(x, y);
 }
```