# Having issues using MouseEvent in HTML canvas animation

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, mouseevent

So I hit a snag while building an HTML5 canvas UI element. I want to make the circle in this toggle switch drag to the X-coordinate that the user drags it to (there's ultimately a lot more that this thing is going to have but I want to do it a step at a time!). I can output the x coordinates so I know that's working but for some reason I cannot get it to work in my animation loop to change the variable `primX`. Here's my code:

**HTML:**

```
<canvas id="toggle1" class="toggle" onmousemove="getCoords(event)"></canvas>
  <p id="test"></p>
```

The CSS is irrelevant, as long as you set any width to .toggle or #toggle1

**JavaScript:**

```
var canvas=document.getElementById("toggle1");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height=cw/3;
var PI=Math.PI;
var PI2=(PI * 2);
var cx=ch/2;
var cy=ch/2;
var backStyle="#FFFFFF"
var globalID;
var lw=ctx.lineWidth=8;
var radius=ch/2-lw/2;
var half=cw/2;
var currX;
var globalID;
var mouseIsDown=false;

function getCoords(event) {
    var currX = event.clientX;
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = currX;
}

function backGround(){  
    if (primX > half){
      Style="#00FF00";
      } else {
      Style="#FF0000";
        };  
  ctx.fillStyle=backStyle;
  ctx.strokeStyle=Style;
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(cx+lw/2,cy,radius,(0.5 * PI),(1.5 * PI));
  ctx.lineTo((cw-(ch/2)),0+lw/2);
  ctx.arc((cw-(ch/2+lw/2)),cy,radius,(1.5 * PI),(.5 * PI));
  ctx.lineTo(cx,ch-lw/2);
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.stroke();
};

function mainCir() {
    if (primX > half){
      Style="#00FF00";
      on=true;
      } else {
      Style="#FF0000";
      on=false;
        };
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(primX,cy,radius,0,PI2);
    ctx.fillStyle=Style;
    ctx.fill();
}

primX = cx;

function draw(){
backGround();
mainCir();
}

draw();

function animate() {
    primX=currX;
    globalID=requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    draw();
}


$("#toggle1").mousedown(function() {
    mouseIsDown=true;
});
$(document).mouseup(function() {
  if(mouseIsDown){
  animate();
  mouseIsDown=false;
}
});
```

I've tried a ton of different things but nothing work. If I put a simple animation in the animate() function then that seems to work when the mouse is clicked and held on the element, such as `primX++;`

But I have no idea how to "animate" the circle to where it goes to the X coordinate that the user drags it to. I've tried a couple of different things and rearranged stuff but it just ends up either disabling animations completely or, as you can see by **[THIS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Doug021786/x9r8qe6o/)** the circle just disappears.

If anyone knows how to fix this issue, I'd be grateful. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a little thing. In the function that get the coordinates:

```
function getCoords(event) {
    var currX = event.clientX;
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = currX;
}
```

you are declaring the `currX` variable. But it was alredy declared, so what you are doing is to create a new one whose scope get lost in the moment the function finish.

You want this:

```
function getCoords(event) {
    currX = event.clientX;
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = currX;
}
```

Hope it helps!

---

**UPDATE**:

There are two more details that maybe are useful for you:

**First**: you are getting the coordinates in the application's client area, not in the canvas. So maybe you want to add the canvas' left offset.

**Second**: `canvas.width` is the logical canvas width, different from the element.width CSS attribute. So most sure you want to make a units conversion.

Altogether:

```
function getCoords(event) {
    currX = event.clientX - $(event.target).offset().left ;
    currX = currX * (canvas.width / $(canvas).width());
    if (currX < radius) currX = radius;
    if (currX > canvas.width - radius) currX = canvas.width - radius;
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = currX;
}
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3011418/onmousemove-get-mouse-position) you can read more about getting mouse coordinates and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4938346/canvas-width-and-height-in-html5) about the dimensions of a canvas.

Comment: It definitely was helpful because I was just about to look up how to make the coordinates only cover the canvas. I especially appreciate how your if statements keep everything in check as far as where the circle can travel. You've been a huge help today David.