# create flashlight effect inside a contained div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm modeling my flashlight effect off of [this tutorial](http://www.mantlelabs.com/flashlight/#.V2v4lpMrKuU).

The problem I'm having is when the window width is larger than my actual container. When this happens, the flashlight is no longer centered on the cursor.

Take a look at this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mL1Ls6vg/) for a better understanding.
Result link on [Fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/mL1Ls6vg/show/)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.content-wrap').mousemove(function(e) {
    $('#flashlight').css({
      'left': e.clientX-960,
      'top': e.clientY-523
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.content-wrap {
  max-width:960px;
  width:100%;
  min-height: 592px;
  margin:0 auto;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: blue;
}

#flashlight {
  background: url(https://s3.amazonaws.com/ip-devs/AllState/keep-your-sanity/img/flashlight.png) center center no-repeat;
  position:absolute;
  z-index:999;
  height:1046px;
  width:1920px;
  pointer-events:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content-wrap">
      <div id="flashlight"></div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

figured out i need to get the position within the div itself and not the screen, so posting my solution here for any future trouble shooting:

```
$('.content-wrap').mousemove(function(e) {
  var x = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
  var y = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;
  $('#flashlight').css({
    'left': x-960,
    'top': y-523
  });
});
```

Check on [**JsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/mL1Ls6vg/5/)

Answer (score 0):

The trick here is the values that set the offset.

```
.content-wrap {
  max-width:960px;
  width:100%;
  min-height: 592px;
```

and

```
'left': e.clientX-960,
'top': e.clientY-523
```

Those values should not be hard-coded.

Answer (score 0):

If your flashligt is absolute relative to the document root, use `e.pageX` instead of `e.clientX` (same for Y) as detailed in this answer: [onMouseMove get mouse position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3011418/onmousemove-get-mouse-position)